# Why text-center has more precedence compared to text-right in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and learning bootstrap 4.  I coded two html file which uses the text-right and text-center classes of bootstrap 4 to a div. The first html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-right text-center">etugoirjbvoidfuhgeruiv</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the first html file worked as expected the text-center class was specified after text-right and overridden text-right. 
But the second html file worked strange. I reversed the order of specification of class and wrote the html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-center text-right">etugoirjbvoidfuhgeruiv</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But still the output is same. the text-right is specified after text-center I thought that the text-right will override text-center but that did'nt happend. Why?

Comment: the order in the class doens't matter, only the order inside the CSS file matter

Comment: do you mean that .text-center is defined after .text-right in bootstrap 4

Comment: yes exactly. check the duplicate it covers many cases and you will understand